# Making the colums of table padding-top:0px - not working

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have a small problem in making the table columns **padding-top:0px** to work.

Please look at the website **wp.allandale.com** and I actually defined a table with 3 columns.
The first column has 3 items : how we did today (survey), business hours & Alberta motor vehicle...
The second column is just a 20px space
The third column is the collection of logos (just one image)

The third one - I am trying to make it padding-top:0px but does not work.

This is the coding (just a short form)

```
<center>
<div>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
              <!-- 3 items here : separated by <br /> -->
        </td> 

        <td>
             <a href="#"><img src="../images/spacer.gif" width="20" height="1" /></a>
        </td> 


        <td style="padding-top:0px;"><img src="../images/biglogo.jpg" /></a>
        </td> 

    </tr>

</table>
</div>
</center>
```

Please let me know what I should do. I am NOT an expert in web development. Just a fresher.

Comment: <td style="padding-top:0px !important;">             try this

Comment: But if I remove <center></center>, its aligning, but I need to have it centered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If what you need to do is pull that image to the top, this works.

```
 vertical-align:top
```

Comment: @Isaac You should always accept an answer so that anyone referring to this question knows what to do.

Answer (score 1):

the problem is not with padding.

currently vertical align is `vertical-align: inherit`

you have to change this to `vertical-align:top`

`<td style="vertical-align: top;"><a href="#"><img alt="" src="../wp-content/uploads/2011/09/anotherdogtag8.jpg"></a></td>`

(or change in css)

Comment: @isaac I have cleaned the code. Please see the updated code